# Show that $\mathcal{G} = \{f \in C[0,1] : \int_0 ^1 f^2 > 1\}$ is open in $C[0,1]$. (Assume $C[0,1]$ has the uniform metric.)

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is exactly as stated above. It seems like an obvious truth, although I am unclear on how to prove that $\mathcal{G}$ is indeed open on the set. Thanks in advance for any advice.

edit: 
Note $f \in C[0,1]$ if $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: what have you tried?  What topology does have $C[0,1])$ ? Does that mean continuous or differentiable?

Comment: Well, I know that when $f \in C[0,1]$, then it must be continuous on that space. So the integral of $f^2$ must also be continuous, and since we are considering where the integral is greater than $1$, it appears to be open. I am confused though as to whether or not this argument is an appropriate proof. It seems too simple, and this was a question on an old qualifying exam for my university, so I wasn't sure quite how to handle it.

Comment: I encourage you to edit the question to include the defintiion of $C[0,1]$ for other users who are not familiar with your notation.  And a short explanation of why you think this is obvious.

Comment: @cactus314: It is fairly usual that $C[0,1]$ comes with the $\sup$ norm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $\phi(f) = \int_0^1 f^2$ is continuous, hence $\phi^{-1} ((1,\infty))$ is open.

Comment: Is it really as simple as arguing this way? I wasn't sure, especially for a qualifying exam.

Comment: Well, you need to establish that $\phi$ is continuous.

Comment: Right, but if that's it, then it really is just as simple as I imagined. I was worried that I was over-simplifying the situation. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: This is one of those answers that add something big to one's knowledge.